# Is it possible to upload and then display an image with straight HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, plugins, file-upload

This is not a question where I have code to post, but just a question on whether or not you can upload an image and then display that image with no server side code (straight HTML with use of JS or Jquery... or any other plugin available).  I am a .Net and Java guy with plenty of experience on MVC, ASP and JSP, but I am wondering if this can be done.  I have been searching for hours and dont see anything, but I know there must be a way.  I have experimented with JotForm and DropBox, but havent come up with anything yet.

I would appreciate no downvotes or sarcasm on this, its a simple question.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding your question. How could you possibly upload an image to a server without any server-side code? (Alternatively: Why do you describe JS and jQuery as "server side code"?)

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: no. Without any server-side language, there is no uploading.

However it is possible to display an image client-side using this code:

```
<input type = "file" id = "my-file-input" />
<img src = "" alt = "" id = "my-image" />

... later ...

<script>
if (window.webkitURL){
  // support for WebKit browsers
  window.URL = window.webkitURL;
}
$("#my-file-input").change(function (ev){
  var data = window.URL.createObjectURL(ev.target.files[0]);

  $("#my-image").attr("src", data);
});
</script>
```

This isn't guaranteed to work cross-browser since `window.URL` is a new HTML5 feature, but it works fine in Firefox and Chrome/Safari.

Comment: So as long as I have an image there...  Trying to get a grasp on "#my-file-input" and "#my-image".  What am I defining?

Comment: Those are CSS selectors for a file input tag and an image tag, respectively. I updated my example to have them, you can change the selectors to whatever you like.

Comment: This might help a little if you are new to jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/